# Concatenate results in SQL and have added text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to try and output some text into a result field as well as the result from two separate fields.

I have a `traveldate` - `datetime` field and a `lastservicedate` - `datetime` field and want to try and output the following into one result field:

Travel services from `traveldate` to `lastservicedate`

Can this be done at all?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
select traveldate, lastservicedate, 
    'Travel services from ' + convert(varchar(20), traveldate) +
    ' to ' + convert(varchar(20), lastservicedate) as TextResult
from tablename
```

Not sure what kind of date format you want, check here for more info on formatting dates with cast and convert: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.